# Comparing old and new field value from Map<Id,Sobject>

Tags: trigger-oldmap, framework

I am pretty new to development and I am trying to user Chris Aldridge's Lightweight Trigger Framework http://chrisaldridge.com/triggers/lightweight-apex-trigger-framework/.

I am looking to create a task related to the lead that was edited if the field value changed. Below is something that I tried and it didn't work. There is also some code that is commented out because it didn't work or I was trying different variations.

Does someone know how it should be written?

```
public static void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
      List<Task> newTasks = new List<Task>();

     for (Lead updatedLead : (List<Lead>) newitems.values())  { 
        //SObject oldLead = oldItems.get(updatedLead.Id);
        //SObject oldLeadValue = oldItems.values();
         //Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedLead.ID); 

        //check to see if the product interest has changed. only want to create a task if the product 
         interest has changed.
        if (updatedLead.ProductInterest__c != oldLead.ProductInterest__c)
           {
            //create a new task related to lead with product interest information
            Task newTask = new Task(
                Subject = 'Follow up with Lead, their Product Interest was updated',
                Status = 'Not Started', 
                WhoId = updatedLead.Id,
                OwnerId = updatedLead.OwnerId,
                Priority = 'Normal');
            //add this new task sObject to our list of tasks
            newTasks.add(newTask);
      } 
    } //end for loop
    //insert the batch of new tasks into Salesforce
    Insert newTasks;
 } //end AfterUpdate method
```

Comment: Did you try `Lead oldLead = (Lead)oldItems.get(updatedLead.Id);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is pretty close.

The general form of what you want is `newRecord.field != oldRecord.field`, it's just a matter of knowing how to access the values.

There are multiple approaches you could take...

### Keeping things as generic SObjects

The trigger frameworks that I've seen pretty much all pass collections (i.e. a list, set, or map) of the generic `SObject` type. The reasons for that are out of scope of this question, but the important part is that when you're working with a generic `SObject`, you need to use `.get('myField')` to read the value of a field instead of using simple dot-notation.

That would turn your if statement into this

`if (updatedLead.get('ProductInterest__c') != oldLead.get('ProductInterest__c'))`

### Type-casting to a more specific SObject Type

Yeah, we can use generic SObjects just fine, but it's usually nicer to work on a specific SObject type (like `Lead` or `Account`).

The type system in Apex has some issues, but you should be able to do an explicit "type-cast" to change the type of your data from `SObject` to `Lead`.

When you type-cast from a generic type to a more specific type, that's called *down-casting* (as opposed to the opposite, going from a more specific type to a more generic type, which is *up-casting*). It isn't possible to do that (down-casting) in every situation, but it should be possible to do here.

Working on a more specific type allows you to use regular 'ol dot notation (`myRecord.myField == 'some value'`) and gives you a bit more safety (as a quick example, you'll be warned about trying to put a `Lead` into a `List<Account>` when you try to save/deploy your code. If you were using a generic SObject, you might not encounter an error until you (or someone else) runs your code).

The change you'd need to make for this would be something like

```
// note that we're doing an explicit cast of the result we get from the oldItems map
Lead oldLead = (Lead)oldItems.get(updatedLead.Id);
```

Comment: thanks for the really clear explanation. I'm glad I wasn't too far off :)
I tried the first part with my code and it worked: 
for (Lead updatedLead : (List<Lead>) newitems.values())  { 
        SObject oldLead = oldItems.get(updatedLead.Id);
if (updatedLead.get('ProductInterest__c') != oldLead.get('ProductInterest__c'))

Answer (score 1):

just iterate on the new Items doing gets on the old Items.
I recommend adjusting types at the beginning of the code, in case you need to use the information again later on

```
public static void AfterUpdate(Map<Id, SObject> newItems, Map<Id, SObject> oldItems) {
    
    Map<Id, Lead> mpNewLead = (Map<Id, Lead>)newItems;
    Map<Id, Lead> mpOldLead = (Map<Id, Lead>)oldItems;
    List<Task> newTasks = new List<Task>();
    
    for(Lead updatedLead : mpNewLead.values()){
        ifif(updatedLead.ProductInterest__c != mpOldLead.get(updatedLead.Id).ProductInterest__c){
            Task newTask = new Task(
                Subject = 'Follow up with Lead, their Product Interest was updated',
                Status = 'Not Started', 
                WhoId = updatedLead.Id,
                OwnerId = updatedLead.OwnerId,
                Priority = 'Normal'
            );
            newTasks.add(newTask);
        }
    }
    Insert newTasks;
 }
```

Comment: HI Pedro, that almost worked. I had to change
 if(updatedLead.ProductInterest__c != oldItems.get(updatedLead.Id).ProductInterest__c){
to
  if(updatedLead.ProductInterest__c != mpOldLead.get(updatedLead.Id).ProductInterest__c){

 can you update your code so I can mark it as the correct answer? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi, LMills. Kind of you to mention.
Sorry for the map name. Glad I could help